# Mongoose populate - Node.JS creating multiple objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate

Task I have is to make a array of i.e. dishes that logged user is selecting as his favourite. Problem is that instead of one array of objectIDs i.e. dishes:[123456,5678910], i get two separate objects for same user with only one dish id in the array.

I presume that problem is in my schema, so can someone give me an idea?

```
var favoriteSchema = new Schema({

timestamps: true,


dishes: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Dish'
}],

postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}

});
```

Edit>> My post method as demanded

```
.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function (req, res, next) {
Favorites.create(req.body, function (err, favorite) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('favorite created!');
    var id = favorite._id;
    favorite.postedBy = req.decoded._doc._id;
    favorite.dishes.push(req.body);
    favorite.save(function (err, favorite) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Updated Favorites!');
        res.json(favorite);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post how you create the entries? Your schema seems OK.

Comment: I have edited the post, and submitted my .post method.
This create method is perhaps my problem, but I am not sure what to use... @Apokalyptra

Comment: How do you get the `id` of a dish to push to the `dishes` array?

Comment: @chridam `favorite.dishes.push(req.body);`

Comment: So `req.body` is the `id` of the dish right, and not just an object? The reason I'm asking is the `dishes` field is an array of dish `id`s, not objects.

Comment: @chidram Yes. The idea is to send dish id via post method and to put it in array of dish id. The post method I written could(probably is) be wrong.
The user that is logged in is obtained this way `favorite.postedBy = req.decoded._doc._id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post method is fine for the first time you want to add a favorite dish. The next time you add a dish for the same user you should call

```
Favorites.findOne({postedBy: req.decoded._doc._id}, function (err, favorite) {
  favorite.dishes.push(req.body);
  favorite.save(function (err, favorite) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(favorite);
    });
})
```

Comment: And surround it in if/else statement I presume?

Comment: Yes, you can do the `findOne` query and based on the return value (`favorite == null`) either create or update the document.